# How to use geolocation of user from browser? Javascript Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, geolocation

I need information of user and share to site. Every user have different `ip address` and other information. Information which I **need**:

```
Address(city)
IP address
Internet Service Provider
Operating System
Browser
```

I using **`Vue.js`** as framework

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. I also suggest searching for it. First hit on "javascript geolocation": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API

Comment: Okay but how to show IP address?
Operating system?

Comment: Show at least a little bit of willingness to figure things out for yourself by searching for it.